# How to setup Rider on Mac OS, Mojave?

Tags: .net, macos, installation, mono, rider

> Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1195, 5): [MSB3644] The reference assemblies for framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2" were not found. To resolve this, install the SDK or Targeting Pack for this framework version or retarget your application to a version of the framework for which you have the SDK or Targeting Pack installed. Note that assemblies will be resolved from the Global Assembly Cache (GAC) and will be used in place of reference assemblies. Therefore your assembly may not be correctly targeted for the framework you intend.
>
> 8:09 PM   .NET Framework is not found: MsBuild can not find TargetFramework assemblies, specify a Mono MSBuild in settings. You can download the latest stable Mono release.

I am trying to set up both Visual Studio and Rider on Macbook running Mojave. I am running into this problem where I have to call for mono building location. I have installed the latest stable Mono but I don't know the location I have to add.

If someone has a video or online document explaining how to install .Net framework on mac, that would be helpful.

[image: Location for Mono Builder]

Here is the additional image to the issue on Rider in Mojave

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Usually Rider automatically detects all installed mono runtimes and take a right one:

[image]

But you can specify your own runtime by selecting 'Custom' in the 'Mono executable path' combo box =)

Comment: Thank you, Rider in my machine also has the same locations but still, I am getting above errors. Can you share the image of the whole settings image, like if you go a little below, it has label "Verbosity of file logger" below that it has some location which is like this, for me, "/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework"?

Comment: Other settings does not affect project loading. So maybe your mono is broken somehow? Try to build your project from command line like `mono <path to msbuild.exe> <solution_name.sln>`

Comment: In my case the input box for the last line on picture (which is "MSBuild solution loading targets") was empty. So I set it to "/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono/msbuild/Current/bin/MSBuild.dll" and it now works! Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Mono on macOS installs into the library "Frameworks", so the base directory of the install ends up being:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/
```

**Note**: I am not sure it is looking for this base dir or one of its subs:

```
├── Commands -> /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/bin
├── External
├── Headers -> /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/include
├── Home -> /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/
├── Libraries -> /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/lib
├── Mono -> /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/lib/libmono-2.0.dylib
└── Versions
```

Comment: Hi, I tried to change the location, it says no write permission for folder

Comment: @Zeus25 If it trying to write into that location, then it is looking for a user-writable location, not the Mono install location...